# RSS Feed Shows Items But XmlReader Pulls Back 0 Items

Tags: c#

I have the following code for reading from an XML feed:

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(blogSettings.RssFeedUrl);
var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
var items = feed.Items.Select(i =>
{
    var link = i.Links.FirstOrDefault()?.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
    var contentEncoded = i.ElementExtensions
        .ReadElementExtensions<string>("encoded", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/");
    var postId = i.ElementExtensions
        .ReadElementExtensions<string>("post-id", "com-wordpress:feed-additions:1");
    return new BlogPost
    {
        Title = i.Title.Text,
        Summary = i.Summary.Text,
        Url = link,
        PostId = postId.FirstOrDefault(),
        PublishDate = i.PublishDate.ToString(),
        Content = contentEncoded,
    };
});
return items;
```

I am in the process of relocating my WordPress blog from [this URL](https://rardk.com/blog/) to [this new URL](https://rardk.com/rardk64-blog/). Browsing directly to the feeds for both [old](https://rardk.com/blog/feed) and [new](https://rardk.com/rardk64-blog/feed) show items as expected. However, when I run my code above, the old feed brings back the items, but the new feed brings back zero items. I've checked and I'm hitting the correct URL, but I get 0 items back in the feed (see image below). Is there something I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: for me [`https://rardk.com/rardk64-blog/feed/`](https://rardk.com/rardk64-blog/feed/) has no items.

Comment: Hmm it displays the items when I open it in my browser...what could cause a feed to have zero items though?

Comment: Just to be clear: This is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXaVE.png Maybe you have cookies / authentication / ip whitelist?

Comment: If the difference really is that you have items in your browser and I don't then that might also explain why your WebRequest/HttpClient call doesn't return items. Can you  repro in IE6 or another decent browser?

Comment: Yeah this is true, if I'm not logged in I see nothing in the RSS. But I've even just tried publishing an entirely new test post and it doesn't show up either, so I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something was messed up with the migration, so because it was easier to just move the post over (I only had one post on the old install anyway) to a whole new WordPress installation rather than try to make this migration work, that's what I went with.